# Is it possible to confront Dagoth Ur from the beginning of the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

Let's suppose someone has just started a new game and has just stepped off the boat in Seyda Neen. Is there anything, aside from the difficulty of the monsters, stopping the player from walking up Red Mountain and confronting Dagoth Ur?

For example, is the Ghost Gate locked until some part of the main quest has been completed? Even so, there's that secret entrance into Red Mountain underneath Kogoruhn that would grant you access into the Ghost Fence.

Additionally, is it absolutely neccesary to to acquire Kagrenac's Tools to defeat Dagoth Ur, or do they simply make him easier to beat? Would a hypothetical infinitely-leveled character still be able to take him down?

Comment: You may find this link interesting: http://speeddemosarchive.com/Morrowind.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is nothing stopping a player from confronting Dagoth Ur right from the start, but you will need Sunder and Keening to actually accomplish anything.

---

Longer answer:

Ghostfence is fairly easy to get past. The gate is IIRC openable right from the start, you can levitate over the fence anyway, and if all else fails, the [Scrolls of Icarian Flight](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Scrolls#Fortify_Skill) can get you pretty much anywhere; just use a second scroll, or any source of [Slowfall](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Slowfall) or  to land, and you're done.

Without [Sunder](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Sunder) and [Keening](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Keening), though, you've no way to actually destroy the heart, so you'll need to go grab those on the way. [Wraithguard](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Wraithguard) can be safely skipped, as long as you have some way to survive the damage caused by the other two artifacts. That's not an easy thing to do, but it is certainly possible. A common method involves getting 100 pts of [Resist Magicka](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Resist_Magicka), since the damage from Sunder/Keening is magical. The [Heart Ring](http://uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Heart_Ring) dropped by Dagoth in the first fight is handy here; even though it only lasts 30 seconds, that's more than enough time to destroy the Heart.

Ultimately, the game can be beaten without ever having to fight anything, or even complete any proper quests beyond the tutorial. But doing so involves running past some very strong enemies without the levels or equipment you normally need to survive them; look up [Morrowind Speedruns on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=morrowind+speedrun) (or anywhere else on the internet speedruns can be found) to see some of the ways people survive the run into Red Mountain.

Comment: Ah, this confirms my original theory. I always imagined there were a lot more ways to "beat" the game than to simply follow the main quest, and that a creative person would be able to do it in ways the developers hadn't imagined. The Speedruns definitely prove it.

Comment: *Apparently*, if you juice your stats high enough via any combination of alchemy, enchanting, or permanent fortify effect abuse, you can stab Dagoth Ur for high enough damage that it rolls over and negates any script/immunity he has. Or it crashes to desktop, I can't remember which.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that when you sadi of the resist Magicka, it was patched since Keening and Sunder is magical and also scripted. The player cannot resist script effects.

Comment: @JimJones Damage from them is too weak to be a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I remember attempting this with cheats way back when. Setting my strength to something like 5000 and killed him in a few minutes. The quest line didn't progress properly though.

With lesser means, aka starting from the boat, it would take forever. I don't see anything else stopping you from getting there, but I would imagine it would take over an hour or more to deal out that kind of damage.

Comment: Cheats?  you don't even need that, just potions ... get some potions of +intelligence (or was it wisdome?), drinks those, then make more potions ... including more of +intellgence.  Keep repeating it, and after a while you'll be making insane potions (eg, a potion of jumping that'll send you high enough to kill you  on landing if you try using it).  Although how I'm able to get enough potion ingredients quickly might be cheating. (find the ones who restock items, sell it back to them, then buy, and it'll set a new max that they restock to)

Comment: Or you know, 2 minutes of looking up console commands out of sheer boredom ( I had over 2500 hours in morrowind).

Comment: Nah, that'd be cheating ... whereas abusing poor QA ... that's fair in my book.  (of course, no one would play C&C with me after a month or so, as I figured out the bug w/ silos)  ... and I don't think I even want to know how many hours I had in morrowind ... almost finished, stopped for a bit, then couldn't remember where I was so started all over again.